# Win API for changing input language programmatically

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, sdk

I want to change the input language in WinXP to Spanish, programmatically. Is there an API to support that?

Thanks

Comment: I'm just curious - why do you want to do this? Are you writing a better UI for picking language?

Comment: No, I have a scenario where user can add a new language keyboard but the application does not  provide him facility to get into control panel. It's an Win Embedded application with only the App UI and nothing else.

Comment: I'm kinda looking for the same thing - a programmatic method to change the input locale in a system-wide manner, or to any application I choose...

Answer (score 10):

- [LoadKeyboardLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646305.aspx)
- [ActivateKeyboardLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646289.aspx)
- [GetKeyboardLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646296.aspx)

etc.

Comment: Thanks Gadu. I noticed that these impact on process level. anything for the system level also?

Comment: Nobody knows. Obviously, tray icon can change language systemwide.

Answer (score 0):

i managed to do it with keyboard events & shortcut assignment.

1. go to "text services and input language" (that's how it's called windows 7 control panel)
2. assign keys for the uni-directional language.  e.g. "To English", and "To Hebrew".  I've chosen Alt-Shift-7 and Alt-Shift-8, because they're rarely used elsewhere.
3. from your app, send the key combination for the appropriate language, when needed.

**Note:**

if "your app" is an external utility (I wrote mine in Python), then it must NOT invoke a window, otherwise /your-app/ will steal the focus, and will get the language change.  in python I solved it by using a GUI-less pyw script filename. (or invoke the script with pythonw.exe)

this article shows how to send keyboard events in python:

https://python-decompiler.com/article/2012-11/how-to-generate-keyboard-events-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Not tried myself, according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setlocaleinfoa) `SetLocaleInfoA` (or `...W` variant – undecorated alias if relying on `UNICODE` setting) does the job on system level.

Don't forget to broadcast the [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange) message as documented.

Comment: Late reply for late readers...