# How to programmatically GET and SET the Input Language by WinAPI from Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-10.4-sydney

How can I **programmatically** GET and SET the **Input** Language by WinAPI from Delphi (that can also be set from the Windows Taskbar):

[image]

Please note: The **Input** Language is NOT the language displayed in Windows UI. The **Input** Language is the language used by specific language-specific keyboard keys at the keyboard input.

Comment: This has probably already been answered in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819665/win-api-for-changing-input-language-programmatically

Answer (score 2):

> GET the Input Language

You can use [GetKeyboardLayoutList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardlayoutlist) and [GetKeyboardLayoutName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardlayoutnamea) to list Keyboard identifier.

Some code: (C++)

```
HKL hklArr[100];
int cnt = GetKeyboardLayoutList(100, hklArr);
if (cnt > 0)
{
    for (UINT i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        if (ActivateKeyboardLayout(hklArr[i], 0))
        {
            CHAR pName[KL_NAMELENGTH];
            if (GetKeyboardLayoutNameA(pName))
            {
                printf("layout name (KLID): %s\n", pName);                  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Debug:

[image]

Then you can get the Input Language based on the keyboard identifier.

Refer：[Keyboard Identifiers and Input Method Editors for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values)

> SET the Input Language

Using [WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-inputlangchangerequest) message,

Some code:

```
HKL hkl = LoadKeyboardLayout(L"00000409", KLF_ACTIVATE);
PostMessage(GetConsoleWindow(), WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST,  0, (LPARAM)hkl);
```

The keyboard will switch to "United States-English".

You can also set the [INPUTLANGCHANGE_FORWARD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-inputlangchangerequest#parameters) parameter, it will use the hot key to select the next input locale in the list of installed input locales.